# java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException

Tags: java, classloader, testng, mockito, powermock

I do experience a really annoying problem with TestNG and RESTeasy.

I do have a class that runs several tests against an API class which uses the RESTeasy framework to expose itself.

However if I let the test run with maven (mvn test), then I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/C:/Users/rit/.m2/repository/org/jboss/resteasy/jaxrs-api/2.3.0.GA/jaxrs-api-2.3.0.GA.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.classtojar:file:/C:/Users/rit/.m2/repository/org/jboss/resteasy/jaxrs-api/2.3.0.GA/jaxrs-api-2.3.0.GA.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class
at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:126)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:96)
at javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder.newInstance(Response.java:394)
at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(Response.java:116)
at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(Response.java:130)
at com.pd.api.TokenAPI_V1.validateAccessToken(TokenAPI_V1.java:141)
at com.test.pd.api.TokenAPI_V1Test.testIfValidAccessTokenReturnsCorrectHTTPHeadersWhenTokenIsNotFound(TokenAPI_V1Test.java:359)
```

The test does nothing more than calling a method of the API obejct which returns a Response object (from RESTeasy). As testing framework I do use TestNG.

**Test Method**

```
@Test
public void testIfValidAccessTokenReturnsCorrectHTTPHeadersWhenTokenIsNotFound() throws InvalidAccessTokenException {
    Mockito.when(tokenService.validateAccessToken(TestConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN)).thenThrow(new InvalidAccessTokenException());

    Response response = tokenAPI_v1.validateAccessToken(TestConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN, TestConstants.USER_AGENT);
    assert "no-store".equals(response.getMetadata().getFirst("Cache-Control"));
    assert "no-cache".equals(response.getMetadata().getFirst("Pragma"));
}
```

**Issue Description**

It looks like the RESTeasy framework loads the RuntimeDelegate in a different class loader. If I take a look at the source code, then there is the following method at the RuntimeDelegate (which covers line 126): [RuntimeDelegate.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.resteasy/jaxrs-api/2.2.2.GA/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.java/#109).

So the main statement that is related to the error is the instanceof check:

```
if (!(delegate instanceof RuntimeDelegate))
```

If I check the classloader of the delegate instance vs the classloader of the RuntimeDelegate, then I get the following output:

```
delegate.getClass().getClassLoader() -> org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader@31e46a68

RuntimeDelegate.class.getClassLoader() -> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@3c0fabe9
```

I am aware of that this of course doesn't work but I wonder why the RESTeasy stuff is loaded in the MockClassLoader and not in the other one. Especially as I don't mock the TokenAPI which gets tested.

**Strange Facts**

The strange thing is, that when I run the tests out of IntelliJ (I choose only to run all tests from the given class which contains the method that produces the error), then it runs through. It looks like it is somehow related to the fact that mvn test runs all tests from the maven project (or at least that's what I guess).

Comment: At least I figured now out how to get the tests running again:

One of the tests uses PowerMockito and as stated in the classloader above, somehow PowerMockito loaded the classes beneath the package jagax.ws.

To disable PowerMockito to load the classes, I've added the javax.ws package to the PowerMockitoIgnore annotation:


@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.ws.*"})

Still I don't get why the test which fails uses the classloader provided by PowerMockito. Is this related to TestNG?

Comment: Hi rit, it actually depends wether those classes were loaded first by the system classloader before or not. Your code certainly reference some JAX-WS classes, which might reference other classe in JAX-WS. The JVM does the linking later to avoid unnecessary load at boot time. So when these classes are used for the first time they are loaded by the PowerMock classloader, but when RESTeasy is started it is loaded using the system classloader, then later type are compared (the instanceof) they are different, because they were loaded in different classloader.
Your solution is the appropriate one.

Comment: If your solution works and is the right one, you can answer your own question.

Comment: mvn test can be instructed to "fork" the tests by the way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't tell you why this happened, but I can tell you how to get around this issue.

The problem was, that PowerMockito scanned tha class path and also added the RESTeasy classes (which are located within the package 'javax.ws.*'. Therefor the above mentioned RuntimeDelegate was loaded by the PowerMockito classloader and caused later the issue, that the class was compared against one from a different classloader.

To get around this issue, tell PowerMockito to ignore the javax.ws package when scanning for classes:

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.ws.*"})
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when deploying my application to JBoss v6.1 - somehow understood that the problem was due to the same package structure of RuntimeDelegate.class existing within jesrey-core and jboss' jaxrs-api jar

Below is my pom.xml

```
    <!-- For Restful Client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For Jackson (JSON Utility) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

After my war is deployed to JBoss, just removed resteasy.deployer folder from jboss' server\default\deployers folder. Ran my application and it worked.

I would be happy if someone explain why this error got resolved this way? (I think JBoss' has unnecessarily shipped with resteasy.deployers jars when developers could include the jars on their own in their apps) - Not to hide that I tried deploying my war on Tomcat and it worked smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by changing `org.glassfish.jersey` version in my `pom.xml`

Below is my `pom.xml`

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.31</version>
 </dependency>
```